# Automatedly vs. Automatically

Tags: meaning

If I have a process which is automated (I have a laundry separator which creates piles based on reflective light wavelengths and material density), can I then say that today I did laundry automatedly?  I wouldn't say automatically; that particular word's definition is overloaded.  One might think that I came home and tended to my laundry without thought.

Instead I would like to describe this action being done by an automatic machine.  This particular word does not seem to have a bona fide definition anywhere.

Comment: *Automation* refers to the machine or process, not to the operator. It's a little awkward to use it to refer to describe *how* you did laundry. Consider saying that you *used the automated laundry* instead.

Comment: You your laundry was done *robotically*.

Answer (score 2):

Automatedly is not a word. Consider a different sentence construction. Instead of, "I did laundry automatedly", use "I did laundry using an automatic process". Also it would be more pleasing to the ear to include a definitive article as in, "I did *the* laundry using an automatic process".

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. Some adverbs sound awkward no matter how you scramble them. When the phraseology strikes you as absurd in a technically correct sentence, you really should consider working around it. As in:

> I used the laundry-separating machine to facilitate the process.

Aesthetically speaking, "automatedly" should not even be a word.